# Can you help me find a problem with this basic C code

Tags: c, while-loop, char, c-strings, function-definition

I'm solving some problems from a C programming book to brush up on Strings. I can't figure out why my solution is not working.

Question asks to write a function named censor that modifies a string by replacing every occurrence of foo by xxx.

My code:

```
int main()
{
    char msg[] = "I love food, you fool.";

    censor(msg);

    puts(msg);

    return 0;
}

void censor(char *str) {
    char *c = str;
    while (c+2 != '\0') {
        if (*c == 'f' && *(c+1) == 'o' && *(c+2) == 'o')
            *c = *(c+1) = *(c+2) = 'x';
        c++;
    }
}
```

I found that the while loop runs for like 1700 times. I'm pretty sure msg[] will include a null character automatically end of string.

Comment: `*(c+i)` is more common as `c[i]`, even `*c` is usually written `c[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking the value of the *pointer*, not what it points to.  So instead of this:

```
while (c+2 != '\0') {
```

You want this:

```
while (*(c+2) != '\0') {
```

Comment: I.e. read compiler warnings, as usual. Even after fixing this with the suggested answer, consider how it will still be broken if ever passed a single-character string, or even an empty string. One could also question the sense in the very existence of `c`, since you could easily just walk the string with `str` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you may not yet use standard C string functions and the function `censor` should be written using pointers.

For starters such a string function should return a pointer to the modified string. That is the function return type should be `char *` instead of `void`.

The condition in the while loop

```
while (c+2 != '\0') {
```

is equivalent to

```
while (c+2 != NULL) {
```

because the expression `c + 2` has the pointer type `char *`. So the condition is incorrect.

Moreover in general if you will even change the condition like

```
while ( *( c+2 ) != '\0') {
```

the loop can have undefined behavior if the user will pass a string that has less than two characters.

The function can be defined as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * censor( char *s ) 
{
    const char *s1 = "foo";
    const char *s2 = "xxx";
    
    for ( char *p = s; *p; )
    {
        const char *t1 = s1;
        
        while ( *t1 && *t1 == *p )
        {
            ++t1; ++p;
        }
        
        p -= t1 - s1;
        
        if ( *t1 == '\0' )
        {
            for ( const char *t2 =s2; *t2; ++t2 )
            {
                *p++ = *t2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ++p;
        }
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char msg[] = "I love food, you fool.";
    
    puts( msg );
    puts( censor( msg ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
I love food, you fool.
I love xxxd, you xxxl
```

The code of the shown function does not depend on the strings `"foo"` and `"xxx"`. The pointers `s1` and `s2` can be initialized with any other strings that have an equal length.